# RxJs how to map the items in an Observable<Array>

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have created some simplified code to illustrate my issue.

My observable emits an array. I am trying to map the items in the array but I am forced to use `Array.map` within the RxJS map operator to achieve this. I am looking for a more RxJs way of achieving the same thing that does not use `Array.map`. Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vooy5) and here is the basic code. Thanks.

```
this.myObservable$ = of(json).pipe(
  map((data: any[]) => {
    return data.map((navigation: any) => {
      return <INavigation> {
        Id: navigation.Id,
        AppId: navigation.NavAppId,
        NavId: navigation.NavId,
        Name: navigation.NavName,
        ParentId: navigation.NavParentId,
        PageURL: navigation.NavPageURL,
        Position: navigation.NavPosition,
        Active: navigation.NavActive,
        Desktop: navigation.NavDesktop,
        Tablet: navigation.NavTablet,
        Phone: navigation.NavPhone,
        RoleId: navigation.NavRoleId,
        Target: navigation.NavTarget
      }
    })
  })
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to use the `map` method of Array but only RxJS operators, than you can leverage the fact that `mergeMap` requires, as parameter, a function which returns an `ObservableInput` and that an Array is an `ObservableInput`.

In this case what `mergeMap` does is to *flatten* the Array and emit its single items (`mergeMap` is also known as `flatMap`).

At the end, since you need an Array to be emitted by `this.myObservable$` you can use the operator `toArray`.

The code looks like this

```
this.myObservable$ = of(json).pipe(
      mergeMap(data => data),
      map((navigation) => {
        return <INavigation> {
          Id: navigation.Id,
          AppId: navigation.NavAppId,
          NavId: navigation.NavId,
          Name: navigation.NavName,
          ParentId: navigation.NavParentId,
          PageURL: navigation.NavPageURL,
          Position: navigation.NavPosition,
          Active: navigation.NavActive,
          Desktop: navigation.NavDesktop,
          Tablet: navigation.NavTablet,
          Phone: navigation.NavPhone,
          RoleId: navigation.NavRoleId,
          Target: navigation.NavTarget
        }
      }),
      toArray()
    )
```

Honestly, your original solution with Array `map` method looks simpler and leaner.

Comment: thanks, good to see an RxJS only solution, will accept if nothing better comes along - I see that maybe my original solution is the more natural but this is the kind of answer I wanted in case there was a natural RxJS'y way - much appreciated

Comment: If you add `tap` operators in between these statements you'll see that the array is being fully transformed to an Observable of items and then again transformed back to an array. There may be a performance hit on this if you have a large array. The original **array** map operator seems more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

RxJS internally uses Javascript Function only, every operator is a javascript function and you can create custom RxJS operator using JS Function.let say you are using [map](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/map.ts) operator, Which will receive the observable as input, perform conversion and return an observable.

You can use Javascript map operator, which is good one. Not seeing any Rxjs operator specific for forEach.